# Testing helper method with using method in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

def sortable(column, title = nil)
title ||= column
css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
sort_arrow = ""
if(column == sort_column)
  if(direction == "desc")
    sort_arrow = "▼"
  elsif(direction == "asc")
    sort_arrow = "▲"
  end
end
link_to sort_arrow+title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction,
                :search_form => @search_form.attributes
}, {:class => css_class}

 end
end
```

this above is the method I would like to test, the problem is that the `sort_column` method is on the controller, therefore I get an error message `method does not exist`. How do I get rid of it or how do I engage the Controller to execute the method?

Edit: 
Controller:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
 def sort_column
  params[:sort] != nil ? params[:sort] : 'ID'
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you add the controller containing the `sort_column` method to your question?

Comment: Did it. I just added the part with the `sort_column` method

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: move the `sortable` method to `ResultsController` with a `helper_method` declaration.

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sortable

  def sort_column
    params[:sort] != nil ? params[:sort] : 'ID'
  end

  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    sort_arrow = ""
    if(column == sort_column)
      if(direction == "desc")
        sort_arrow = "▼"
      elsif(direction == "asc")
        sort_arrow = "▲"
      end
    end
    link_to sort_arrow + title,
            {:sort => column, :direction => direction,
             :search_form => @search_form.attributes},
            {:class => css_class}

  end
end
```

Comment: Is there an hard way?

Comment: Probably, but you probably don't want to use it :)

Comment: The thing is, I'd like to avoid moving the helper method into the Controller

Comment: Why, though? It'll function exactly the same.